# Android Assets without context

Tags: java, android, assets

regarding the Android Assets manager, is it possible to get a file from the assets without context? I read that I can initialize a File object with "file:///android_assets" kind of path, and then get the file from there, but it says that the file does not exist (Honeycomb).

What is the general workaround around this issue? There is no any way to get the context on the place I need the files from the assets.

Thanks

Comment: May we know why can't you get the context in this place?

Comment: because I have a proprietary staff which does everything from the UI parts and staff, and I get those as libs, and then I have only a class that needs to implement some interface, at that point I don't have Context.

Comment: So why won't you pass context as an argument?

Comment: because the place where the context is created (the Activity) is not accessible. It's library that I use.. binary part.

Answer (score 4):

To get access to the Context where it's not present you can extend Application class and create the static reference to the Context. This way you can access it from anywhere within the application:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: It does seem to be the best solution, here in 2016

Comment: This is not a good option, please use dependency injection to inject context dependencies. There are libraries to do this: Dagger 2(google), Dagger(square), Guice etc.